# Changing value of selectbox on change event of another select box from database in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a view file as

```
<select name="tournaments" id ="tournaments" class="form-control">
<?php foreach ($tournaments as $tournament): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $tournament->TournamentID ?>"><?php echo $tournament->TournamentName ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

A script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var initial_target_html = '<option value="">Please select a Tournament...</option>'; //Initial prompt for target select
        $('#matches').html(initial_target_html);
        $("#tournaments").change(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = ($("#tournaments").val());
            $('#matches').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
             $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url:"<?php echo base_url('admin/dashboard/update_match_box') ?>",
                data: {tournament:data},
               success: function(data) {

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller function is

```
public function update_match_box()
{
    $sql = "Some query"
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $json= $query->result();
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($json));
}
```

Controller file is going to return multiple rows, which I need to capture in success event of ajax and update second select box accordingly, how am I suppose to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at form_helper file, there is a lot of useful functions in it for building form inputs, all you have to do is load this helper :
In application/config/autoload.php go to "helper" and add the helper name as follow :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

Next, go to your view file and change this :

```
<select name="tournaments" id ="tournaments" class="form-control">
<?php foreach ($tournaments as $tournament): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $tournament->TournamentID ?>"><?php echo $tournament->TournamentName ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

to this :

```
<?php 
// $tournaments must me an array, use ->result_array() instead of ->result_object()
$tournaments = array_column($tournaments, 'TournamentName', 'TournamentID');
echo form_dropdown('tournaments', $tournaments, '', 'id="tournaments" class="form-control") 
?>
```

For your success callback function, you can use $.each or just for loop to extract each element and create options for the select input:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  url:"<?php echo base_url('admin/dashboard/update_match_box') ?>",
  data: {tournament:data},
  success: function(data) {
    $('select#secondSelect').html('');
    $.each(data, function(item) {
        $("<option />").val(item.id)
                       .text(item.name)
                       .appendTo($('select#secondSelect'));
    });
  }
});
```